# Find a date specific days/months ago using R

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I obtain today's date by using:

```
> today <- format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d")
> # or use `today <- format(Sys.Date())`
> today
[1] "2021-12-23"
```

I hope to find a date specific days/months (let's use **60 days** or **2 months** as example) ago, how could I do that in R?

The equivalent code in Python would be:

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

day1 = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=60)
day2 = datetime.date.today() - relativedelta(months=2)
print(day1)
2021-10-24
print(day2)
2021-10-23
```

Sincere thanks for your help at advance.

Comment: FYI: There is a `Sys.Date()` function to return today's date without the time portion.

Comment: Good to know, thanks, I add that as comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `lubridate` you can simply add subtract days/months etc. like this.

```
library(lubridate)

today <- format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d")

today

ymd(today) - days(60)

ymd(today) - months(2)
```

```
> today
[1] "2021-12-23"
> 
> ymd(today) - days(60)
[1] "2021-10-24"
> 
> ymd(today) - months(2)
[1] "2021-10-23"
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, I was thought we need to use `difftime()` function.